# Django add data from queryset to context

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to add to template the `media` values so in the view I get the value in the `get_queryset` and then add them to template with `get_context`, but something is wrong :

```
class LaLista(ListView):

   def get_queryset(self, **kwargs): 
        qs = super(LaLista, self).get_queryset()
        media = qs.aggregate(Avg('A_U'), Max('A_U'), Min('A_U'))
        return qs, media

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LaLista, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['media'] = media
        return context
```

in the template I have given:

```
{{ media }}
```

and this will return:

> NameError: global name 'media' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a variable `media` in function `get_context_data`, but you don't have the variable defined in the function. Python variables are bound within function scope so you cannot use it without defining it first.

You shouldn't query for `media` in function `get_queryset`, because `get_queryset` is meant to get the queryset that `ListView` will iterate in the template, so it should return only ONE result. If you want extra context, do it in function `get_context_data`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(LaLista, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    # if you didn't define anything special, object_list is the default queryset name
    qs = kwargs['object_list']
    media = qs.aggregate(Avg('A_U'), Max('A_U'), Min('A_U'))
```

Comment: Just changed kwargs to self.object_list and work fine.Thank you!